# How to replace spaces in a variable with plus symbol. Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

So, I have been working on a Batch code that should search things up in google.
The problem is when the user enters 1 keyword it all works perfectly fine, but if the user enters multiple words then it searches up only the first word. Basically I would need a way to replace all of the spaces in the variable with a + symbol.

Code:

```
set /p Input="WEB:> "

start www.google.com/search?q=%Input%
```

Thanks!

Comment: ```start "https://www.google.com/search?q=%Input%"``` ?

Comment: You don't need to replace spaces (see @Hackoo's answer), but to just answer your literal question (replace spaces in a variable with `+`): `%input: =+%`

Answer (score 2):

You should write with double quotes and add a `title` with the command `start`

- Syntax of [Start /?](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

```
@echo off
set /p Input="WEB:> "
start "search" "www.google.com/search?q=%Input%"
```